# Regex Validation 2 characters and "-" and 8 digit numbers

Tags: regex, validation

I have a format like "AA-12345678" and i want to input regex. Actually i want to link both "\p{Lu}+" and "^[0-9]*$" with a specific character like "-".

How can i do that ?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You need the most used and least known regex operator : the concatenation operator !

Comment: Aside from my previous comment jokingly telling you to put your regexes one next to the other, you will need to remove the "start-of-text" `^` anchor from the second regex and move it to the start of your resulting regex. There's nothing particular with `-` when it's not in a `[character class]`, so write it as is.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `^[A-Z]{2,2}-[0-9]{8,8}$`

You can find the demo here - [Link](https://regex101.com/r/9K0olC/1)

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions based on a single sample... OP probably has good reasons to ask for `\p{Lu}` (which on the ascii space will at least diverge from your class on lowercases), and might want to match strings with different amounts of letters and digits.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to explain details

^[A-Z]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,8}$
That means 1 to 2 UpperCase Letters and - and 1 to 8 Digits

and it is meaningful to me.